# Task manager close is not detected second time in a WinForms Application

Tags: c#, winforms, detect, taskmanager, application-close

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show(this, "Do you really want to close?", "Close?", 
                            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

So when I want to close the application clicking the close button the message box is shown as it should, then I chose no. Then the line e.Cancel = true is executed and the form is not closed.

Now the thing is, after this if i close the application from task manager the close reason is UserClosing !!! Why? Shouldn't it be TaskManagerClosing?

Comment: OMG, I was totally able to reproduce this: If TaskManager tries to close the form after a UserClosing was cancelled, the TaskManager's closing attempt is passed with UserClosing as CloseReason, instead of TaskManagerClosing as usual. Is it a bug? Is this expected behavior? Good question, +1!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a [thread](http://dotnet.itags.org/web-forms/86331/) with an answer by our very own [nobugz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/nobugz):

> Windows Forms cannot detect that the
>   close reason came from the Task
>   Manager. So it automatically
>   translates CloseReason.None to
>   CloseReason.TaskManagerClosing.
>   Problem is, once you tried to close
>   with the "X", the CloseReason is set
>   to UserClosing and doesn't get reset
>   back to None if you cancel the close.
>   Sloppy.

And next to it, an explanation by another user on how to change e.CloseReason's value to None using Reflection (since it is read-only), to work-around this problem (this should be applied when setting e.Cancel to True):

```
FieldInfo fi = typeof(Form).GetField("closeReason", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

fi.SetValue(this, CloseReason.None);
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623756/c-detect-reason-for-form-closing/1623983#1623983) to this question which uses [`CloseReason.TaskManagerClosing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.closereason.aspx) to catch the same.

Comment: The code in the link detects whether the close is due to a button click or from windows x button click. Using a bool property to detect is ok here. But how to detect TaskManager closing?

Answer (score 1):

Just the translation of you code in VB:

```
Imports System.Reflection
Private Sub ResetCloseReason()
  Dim myFieldInfo As FieldInfo
  Dim myType As Type = GetType(Form)
  myFieldInfo = myType.GetField("closeReason", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or _
                    BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.Public)
  myFieldInfo.SetValue(Me, CloseReason.None)
```

`End Sub`