# How to know user has clicked "X" or the "Close" button?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In MSDN I found `CloseReason.UserClosing` to know that the user had decided to close the form
but I guess it is the same for both clicking the X button or clicking the close button.
So how can I differentiate between these two in my code?

Thanks all.

Comment: which close button do you mean?

Comment: for example closing by "ALT+F4"

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623756/c-detect-reason-for-form-closing

Comment: [Detect if the Form has closed using X button/Alt+F4/System menu or using Close method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58790227/3110834)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

#### How to detect if the form closed by click on X button or by calling `Close()` in code?

You cannot rely on close reason of the form closing event args, because:
if the user click X button on title bar or
close the form using Alt + F4 or
use system menu to close the form or
the form get closed by calling [`Close()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.close?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) method,

for all of above cases, the close reason will be *Closed by User* (`CloseReason.UserClosing`), which is not desired result.

To distinguish if the form closed by X button or by `Close` method, you can use either of the following options:

- Handle [`WM_SYSCOMMAND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-syscommand?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and check for `SC_CLOSE` and set a flag.
- Check the [`StackTrace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) to see if any of the frames contain `Close` method call.

**Example 1 - Handle `WM_SYSCOMMAND`**

```
public bool ClosedByXButtonOrAltF4 {get; private set;}
private const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;
private const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
protected override void WndProc(ref Message msg)
{
    if (msg.Msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND && msg.WParam.ToInt32() == SC_CLOSE)
        ClosedByXButtonOrAltF4 = true;
    base.WndProc(ref msg);
}
protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
{
    ClosedByXButtonOrAltF4 = false;
}   
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (ClosedByXButtonOrAltF4)
        MessageBox.Show("Closed by X or Alt+F4");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Closed by calling Close()");
}
```

**Example 2 - Checking StackTrace**

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (new StackTrace().GetFrames().Any(x => x.GetMethod().Name == "Close"))
        MessageBox.Show("Closed by calling Close()");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Closed by X or Alt+F4");
}
```

Answer (score 108):

Assuming you're asking for WinForms, you may use the [FormClosing() event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing.aspx). The event FormClosing() is triggered any time a form is to get closed.

To detect if the user clicked either X or your CloseButton, you may get it through the sender object. Try to cast sender as a Button control, and verify perhaps for its name "CloseButton", for instance.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
    if (string.Equals((sender as Button).Name, @"CloseButton"))
        // Do something proper to CloseButton.
    else
        // Then assume that X has been clicked and act accordingly.
}
```

Otherwise, I have never ever needed to differentiate whether X or CloseButton was clicked, as I wanted to perform something specific on the FormClosing event, like closing all MdiChildren before closing the MDIContainerForm, or event checking for unsaved changes. Under these circumstances, we don't need, according to me, to differentiate from either buttons.

Closing by <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> will also trigger the FormClosing() event, as it sends a message to the Form that says to close. You may cancel the event by setting the

```
FormClosingEventArgs.Cancel = true.
```

In our example, this would translate to be

```
e.Cancel = true.
```

Notice the difference between the FormClosing() and the [FormClosed()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closed.aspx) events.

FormClosing occurs when the form received the message to be closed, and verify whether it has something to do before it is closed.

FormClosed occurs when the form is actually closed, so after it is closed.

Does this help?

Comment: I get 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' when I use this code.

Comment: This is wrong. You can't cast sender to button because it's the form itself. This throws exception.

Comment: @WillMarcouiller: Please consider fixing the misinformation about being able to cast to button, given that your answer is the accepted one and has so many up-votes.

Comment: I don't understand? Is SO taken over by bots? How can a clearly wrong answer be upvoted so much. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 89):

The `CloseReason` enumeration you found on MSDN is just for the purpose of checking whether the user closed the app, or it was due to a shutdown, or closed by the task manager, etc...

You can do different actions, according to the reason, like:

```
void Form_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
        // Prompt user to save his data

    if(e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown)
        // Autosave and clear up ressources
}
```

But like you guessed, there is no difference between clicking the x button, or rightclicking the taskbar and clicking 'close', or pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F4</kbd>, etc. It all ends up in a [`CloseReason.UserClosing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.closereason(v=vs.110).aspx) reason.

Comment: Using the standard Close(); seems to trigger CloseReason.UserClosing for me. Not sure why.

Comment: I found this useful when trying to block the closing of an MDI child form by user action on the form but not when the parent is being closed.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, only enumerate further the issue.

Answer (score 57):

The "X" button registers as `DialogResult.Cancel` so another option is to evaluate the `DialogResult`.

If you have multiple buttons on your form, you're probably already associating different `DialogResult`s to each and this will provide you with the means to tell the difference between each button.

(Example: `btnSubmit.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK`, `btnClose.DialogResult = Dialogresult.Abort`)

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.FormClosing += Form1_FormClosing;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Override the Close Form event
    /// Do something
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void Form1_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        //In case windows is trying to shut down, don't hold the process up
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown) return;

        if (this.DialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            // Assume that X has been clicked and act accordingly.
            // Confirm user wants to close
            switch (MessageBox.Show(this, "Are you sure?", "Do you still want ... ?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question))
            {
                //Stay on this form
                case DialogResult.No:
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: In my case this is more useful than the accepted answer. Since the 'X' is assigned DialogResult.Cancel, assigning some other value to the cancel button easily distinguish them and handle things appropriately.

Comment: This doesn't work in my case. When press 'X', `DialogResult` remains `None`. What could be the problem?

Comment: @Bhaskar, when you instantiate your dialog, make sure to set the appropriate DialogResult to each button in your dialog. I had provided an example above but did not create a code block to show the Dialog declaration.

Comment: @Bhaskar: Pressing `X` makes `DialogResult` contain `Cancel`, not `None`. Assigning `None` to your button is the same as not setting its `.DialogResult` property at all, and if you call `form.Close()` from your button's event handler, `form.DialogResult` will contain `Cancel`. Only assigning a value other than `None` or `Cancel` to all your form-closing buttons will allow you to make the desired distinction.

Answer (score 8):

It determines when to close the application if a form is closed (if your application is not attached to a specific form).

```
    private void MyForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Application.OpenForms.Count == 0) Application.Exit();
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I always use a Form Close method in my applications that catches alt + x from my exit Button, *alt + f4* or another form closing event was initiated. All my classes have the class name defined as Private string `mstrClsTitle = "grmRexcel"` in this case, an Exit method that calls the Form Closing Method and a Form Closing Method. I also have a statement for the Form Closing Method - `this.FormClosing = My Form Closing Form Closing method name`.

The code for this:

```
namespace Rexcel_II
{
    public partial class frmRexcel : Form
    {
        private string mstrClsTitle = "frmRexcel";

        public frmRexcel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.FormClosing += frmRexcel_FormClosing;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the Button Exit Event executed by the Exit Button Click
        /// or Alt + x
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            this.Close();        
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the Form Closing event
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void frmRexcel_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {

            // ---- If windows is shutting down, 
            // ---- I don't want to hold up the process
            if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown) return;
            {

                // ---- Ok, Windows is not shutting down so
                // ---- either btnExit or Alt + x or Alt + f4 has been clicked or
                // ---- another form closing event was intiated
                //      *)  Confirm user wants to close the application
                switch (MessageBox.Show(this, 
                                    "Are you sure you want to close the Application?",
                                    mstrClsTitle + ".frmRexcel_FormClosing",
                                    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question))
                {

                    // ---- *)  if No keep the application alive 
                    //----  *)  else close the application
                    case DialogResult.No:
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I also had to register the closing function inside the form's "InitializeComponent()" method:

```
private void InitializeComponent() {
// ...
this.FormClosing += FrmMain_FormClosing;
// ...
}
```

My "FormClosing" function looks similar to the given answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2683846/3323790):

```
private void FrmMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing){
        MessageBox.Show("Closed by User", "UserClosing");
    }

    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown){
        MessageBox.Show("Closed by Windows shutdown", "WindowsShutDown");
    }
}
```

One more thing to mention: There is also a "FormClosed" function which occurs after "FormClosing". To use this function, register it as shown below:

```
this.FormClosed += MainPage_FormClosed;

private void MainPage_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
// your code after the form is closed
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding event handler from design like this: Open form in design view, open properties window or press F4, click event toolbar button to view events on Form object, find FormClosing event in Behavior group, and double click it.
Reference: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9bdee708-db4b-4e46-a99c-99726fa25cfb/how-do-i-add-formclosing-event?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 2):

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class Member : Form
    {
        public Member()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private bool xClicked = true;

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            xClicked = false;
            Close();
        }

        private void Member_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (xClicked)
            {
                // user click the X
            } 
            else 
            {
                // user click the close button
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (this.DialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            switch (e.CloseReason)
            {
                case CloseReason.UserClosing:
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
```

if condition will execute when user clicks 'X' or close button on form. The else can be used when user clicks Alt+f4 for any other purpose

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the `DialogResult`-Solution as the more straight forward one.

In VB.NET however, typecast is required to get the `CloseReason`-Property

```
    Private Sub MyForm_Closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing

        Dim eCast As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs
        eCast = TryCast(e, System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs)
        If eCast.CloseReason = Windows.Forms.CloseReason.None Then
            MsgBox("Button Pressed")
        Else
            MsgBox("ALT+F4 or [x] or other reason")
        End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done something like this.

```
private void Form_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((sender as Form).ActiveControl is Button)
        {
            //CloseButton
        }
        else
        {
            //The X has been clicked
        }
    }
```

Comment: Works for me, suggest

Answer (score 1):

This, through `Program.cs`, leads to opening some forms and closing other forms when we don't need them.
To do this, in the Program.cs class
before `[STAThread]` line, add this code:

```
public static Form currentopenedform { get; set; }
```

then, enter the following codes instead of ("Application.Run(new Form1());"):

```
try
{
    currentopenedform = new Form1();
    while (currentopenedform != null)
    {
        Application.Run(currentopenedform);
    }
}catch { }
```

These codes make it always check whether the software should open the new form or if the value is null, it should finish the job.
Now, anywhere you want, and on any form, and on any button or anywhere else, you can set a new form to open and close the current form.

```
Program.currentopenedform = new Form2();this.Close();
```

or in form2 ,you can set a new form to open and close the current form.

```
    Program.currentopenedform = new Form1();this.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

This method is vaild.

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (new StackTrace().GetFrames().Any(x => x.GetMethod().Name == "Close"))
        MessageBox.Show("Closed by calling Close()");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Closed by X or Alt+F4");
}
```

Reference by this page.