# .NET Windows Forms - intercepting the Close X event

Tags: .net, winforms

This must be a dumb question, but I cannot figure it out. I also cannot use the designer because coders before me managed to throw GUI and logic all in one, so now it is confused. I've got to do it the old school way.

I have a Form which can be closed in 3 ways: Close button, File / Close menu, and the X icon. I want them all to do the same thing. Intercepting the button and the menu events is easy. In fact, both are hooked up to an `onCloseConfig` method. Btw, is there a better name for this method?

```
private void onCloseConfig(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (! m_configControl.Modified)
    {
        Application.Exit(); // Or should it be this.Close();
    }
    ....
    // Else present a dialog, ask if they want to save.
}
```

So, to intercept the `X` I tried: `this.FormClosing +=new FormClosingEventHandler(this.onCloseConfig);` I believe this is what causes an infinite loop. I do not want that :) `FormClosed` is another option, but it seems too late. I just want to intercept the fact that the X was clicked, not the fact that the form is closing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you do want form closing, the thing you may be missing is to check the reason for closing and only cancel it if it is from the user e.g.

```
private void my_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
  {
    e.Cancel = true; //I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that.
  }
}
```

to hide the 'X' set `Form.ControlBox = false`, but this will get rid of min/max as well.

Comment: Cool! Is there a way to hide X altogether?

Comment: Not without rolling your own window chrome.

Comment: you can get rid of the min max and close though

Comment: I also check for TaskManagerClosing and WindowsShutDown close reasons

Comment: That might be a stupid question. We used FormClosing in past projects. In the actual one we also used it, but the form itself is closed before the first line of code in FormClosing is executed. Is there anything which can be catched before?

Answer (score 3):

Create a separate method for the button/menu close:

```
private void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}

private void myMenuButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}

private void myForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (m_configControl.Modified)
    {
        var result = MessageBox.Show("Name Of Application", "Would you like to save before closing?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
        if(result == DialogResult.Yes)
            //Save here
        else if(result == DialogResult.Cancel)
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Or, you can disable the close-button ("X") altogether by setting `this.ControlBox = false`

Answer (score 1):

> Btw, is there a better name for this
>   method?

Close[FormName] could be a better choice.

> Or should it be this.Close();

Yes, if all you want is to close the form.

You should create a new event handler for FormClosing event. It takes in FormClosingEventArgs and not EventArgs as a parameter. In the click handlers of the button and menu item, just do a this.Close().

This will call the event and you can place all your checks there.

Answer (score 1):

The [FormClosed event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed.aspx) occurs once the form is closed. That is definitely not what you want.

The [FormClosing event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx) is more likely what you need.

The FormClosing event is triggered whatever button or menu link is clicked. Anything that tries to close the form will trigger the FormClosing event.

Now, the more appropriate way to use the [FormClosingEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.aspx) would be the following within your FormClosing event handler method:

```
if(m_configControl.Modified)
    e.Cancel = true;
```

so unless the config control is modified, the form will keep closing. You want to prevent it from closing only if there are changes or unsaved changes.

**EDIT 2** After rereading your question, see below my changes to the upper code:

```
if(m_configControl.Modified)
    if(DialogResult.OK == MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save changes?", "Changes detected")
        SaveChanges();
```

This will then prompt the user for unsaved changes and save only if the user clicked OK in the MessageBox. Note that you will have to add the buttons accordingly in the additional parameters of the MessageBox.Show() method.

If you want to accomplish an Yes/No/Cancel upon FormClosing, then you will have to go this way:

```
if(m_configControl.Modified) {
    DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show(...);
    switch(dr) {
        case DialogResult.OK:
            SaveChanges();
            break;
        case DialogResult.No:
            // Do nothing...
            break;
        case DialogResult.Cancel:
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

So, when the user clicks Yes, your application will save the changes. When he clicks No, the application will do nothing about it and will continue its closing. When the user wishes to come back to the application, then Close will be prevented.

**EDIT 1** Take an eye out on my answer to [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683679/how-to-know-user-has-clicked-x-or-the-close-button/2683716#2683716) which seems quite what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

This should stop window from closing:
FormClosing(object sender, System.EventArts e)
{
if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing) 
      e.Cancel = true; 
}

Comment: System.EventArts [sic] or EventArgs don't have a CloseReason member, you need FormClosingEventArgs as in my answer