# Checking what closed your Windows Form in Powershell

Tags: forms, winforms, powershell

Was wondering if there is a way to check what event closed the window, pretty much either clicking **the red x** in the top corner or if `$form.Close()` was called?

Each will automatically initiate the `$form.Add_Closing({})` if I have it in my script, but I wanted to know which way of closing the window did this.

Comment: [See the `Closing` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.closing?view=netframework-4.8) on the msdn.  You can utilize the `CancelEventArgs` object by adding a `param` block to your scriptblock to match the signature.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58790227/3110834

Comment: @mklement0 tbf, they didn't explicitly state one or the other *in* the question.  [Relevant documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Thanks, @TheIncorrigible1, that is the right link, but to save others time: The event arguments of the `FormClosing` event do _not_ allow you to distinguish between whether the form was closed via a call to `.Close()` or by the user via the close button in title bar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`FormClosing` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing) argument object's `.CloseReason` property doesn't allow you to distinguish between the `.Close()` method having been called on the form and the user closing the form via the title bar / window system menu / pressing <kbd>Alt+F4</kbd> - all these cases equally result in the [`.CloseReason` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.closereason?view=netframework-4.8) reflecting enumeration value [`UserClosing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.closereason).

However, you can adapt the technique from [Reza Aghaei's helpful C# answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58790227/3110834) on the subject, by inspecting the call stack for a call to a `.Close()` method:

```
using assembly System.Windows.Forms
using namespace System.Windows.Forms
using namespace System.Drawing

# Create a sample form.
$form = [Form] @{
    ClientSize      = [Point]::new(400,100)
    Text            = 'Closing Demo'
}    

# Create a button and add it to the form.
$form.Controls.AddRange(@(
    ($btnClose = [Button] @{
        Text              = 'Close'
        Location          = [Point]::new(160, 60)
    })
))

# Make the button call $form.Close() when clicked.
$btnClose.add_Click({
  $form.Close()
})

# The event handler called when the form is closing.
$form.add_Closing({
  # Look for a call to a `.Close()` method on the call stack.
  if ([System.Diagnostics.StackTrace]::new().GetFrames().GetMethod().Name -ccontains 'Close') {
    Write-Host 'Closed with .Close() method.'
  } else {
    Write-Host 'Closed via title bar / Alt+F4.'
  }
})

$null = $form.ShowDialog() # Show the form modally.
$form.Dispose()            # Dispose of the form.
```

If you run this code and try various methods of closing the form, a message indicating the method used should print (`.Close()` call vs. title bar / <kbd>Alt+F4</kbd>).

Note:

- Closing the form via buttons assigned to the form's `.CancelButton` and `.SubmitButton` properties that don't have explicit `$form.Close()` calls still causes `.Close()` to be called behind the scenes.
- The code requires PowerShell v5+, but it can be adapted to earlier versions.

Answer (score 2):

Checking call stack works fine and you can rely on it.

Just for the sake of completeness, specially for cases that you find a C# example and you want to use it in PowerShell in an easy way, I'll share an example showing how you can handle `WM_SYSCOMMAND` as shown in my [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58790227/3110834), in PowerShell.

```
using assembly System.Windows.Forms
using namespace System.Windows.Forms
using namespace System.Drawing

# Create the C# derived Form
$assemblies = "System.Windows.Forms", "System.Drawing"
$code = @'
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class MyForm:Form
{
    public bool ClosedByXButtonOrAltF4 { get; private set;}
    public const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;
    public const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message msg)
    {
        if (msg.Msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND && msg.WParam.ToInt32() == SC_CLOSE)
            ClosedByXButtonOrAltF4 = true;
        base.WndProc(ref msg);
    }
    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
    {
        ClosedByXButtonOrAltF4 = false;
    }    
}
'@
Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $assemblies -TypeDefinition $code -Language CSharp   

# Create an instance of MyForm.
$form = [MyForm] @{
    ClientSize      = [Point]::new(400,100)
    Text            = "Closing Demo"
}    

# Create a button and add it to the form.
$form.Controls.AddRange(@(
    ($btnClose = [Button] @{
        Text              = "Close"
        Location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point 160, 60
    })
))

# Make the button call $form.Close() when clicked.
$btnClose.add_Click({
  $form.Close()
})

# The event handler called when the form is closing.
$form.add_Closing({
  if ($form.ClosedByXButtonOrAltF4) {
    Write-Host 'Closed via title bar / Alt+F4.'
  } else {
    Write-Host 'Closed with .Close() method.'
  }
})

$null = $form.ShowDialog()
$form.Dispose()
```