# How can I show MessageBox with suggestion of saving changes when I'm killing program from task manager?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a program and want show MessageBox with suggestion of saving changes, when I'm trying to kill it from task manager. How can I do it?

Comment: Your form has an event handler for Form.Closing. In this event handler you receive the reason for the closing. Just handle it. You can even stop the closing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623756/detect-reason-for-form-closing

Comment: Thanks very much Steve! I tried the code that you linked me, and it's work great :)

Comment: It works when i'm finishing program from task manager. Can i do something like this when i'm finishing a process from TM ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When **killing** an application from `Task Manager` you are simply terminating the application without continuing with the code. This means no more code execution. That cannot be handled.

It's like telling an employee "you are fired with immediate effect, pack and leave now" but still expect them to finish writing the application that will take 6 months to complete.

Answer (score 1):

There is **NO** way you can execute any code in your application when it is being **Killed** by operating system or user. That's why its called Killing.

Comment: Before downvote, please ensure that you can say otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

In your principal form you can use even FormClosing as :

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {

            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Sure", "Some Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if(dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                //do something
            }
            else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
            {
                e.Cancel=true ;
            }
     }
```